# How to shut-off NIC of a Virtual Machine

Tags: mongodb, virtual-machine, nic, centos8, teraterm

I am testing MongoDB in terms of Network Failure.
**How can I shut-off NIC in a virtual machine.**
I am using terminal: **Teraterm**.
I have a virtual machine running on **CentOS8**.

Comment: Teraterm is a terminal, not a VM solution.

Comment: I am running the virtual machine in Teraterm.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on virtual machine software. In VirtualBox, there are icons in bottom right of the UI that allow attaching/detaching the network adapter.

Comment: I see but I'm using TeraTerm terminal not VirtualBox